# Do mongodb databases within a cluster share the same node set under the hood?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

The reason I am asking is, I have a resource-intensive collection that degrades performance of its entire database. I need to decide whether to migrate other collections away to a different database within the same cluster or to a different cluster altogether.

The answer I think depends on under-the-hood implementation. Does a poorly performing collection take resources only from its own database, or from the cluster as a whole?

Hosted on Atlas.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest first look at your logical and schema designs and try to optimize it but if that is not working then

**"In MongoDB Atlas, all databases within a cluster share the same set of nodes (servers) and are subject to the same resource limitations. Each database has its own logical namespace and operates independently from the other databases, but they share the same underlying hardware resources, such as CPU, memory, and I/O bandwidth.
So, if you have a resource-intensive collection that is degrading performance for its entire database, migrating other collections to a different database within the same cluster may not significantly improve performance if the resource bottleneck is at the cluster level. In this case, you may need to consider scaling up the cluster or upgrading to a higher-tier plan to increase the available resources and improve overall cluster performance."**

Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/creating-a-new-database-vs-a-new-collection-vs-a-new-cluster/99187/2

Comment: "if the resource bottleneck is at the cluster level"? Aren't they always at the cluster level, in light of the above? Seems like a contradiction.

Comment: that's what i said, if schema design and logical designs are optimized then you should consider moving your bad performing collection in completely new cluster.

Answer (score 2):

The term "cluster" is overloaded.  It can refer to a replica set or to a sharded cluster.

A sharded cluster is effectively a group of replica set with a query router.

If you are using a sharded cluster, you can design a sharding strategy that will put the busy collection on its own shard, the rest of the data on the other shard(s), and still have a common point to query them both.

Comment: But, don't different shards share  the same node set?

Comment: No, each shard is a replica set with its own nodes.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I am referring to different shards of different collections; not different shards of the same colletction.

Comment: What you are referring to are called [chunks](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/#data-partitioning-with-chunks).  Each collection is split into chunks, which are stored in [shards](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#shards), you can control via [zones](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/zone-sharding/#zones) which chunks of which collections are stored in a shard.

Comment: Just to be clear: this solves performance problems caused by a misbehaving collection degrading other collections?